# What do you exactly mean by HashMap's iterator is fail-fast and HashTable's enumerator isn't?

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, hashtable, enumerator

I was looking up the difference between the two classes and this point came up in a lot of the answers with this blog being the source: 
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/difference-between-hashmap-and.html

However I don't completely get it.
Can someone elaborate this? Perhaps with an example?

Thanks for looking in!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fail-fast means when you try to modify the content when you are iterating thru it, it will fail and throw ConcurrentModificationException.

```
Set keys = hashMap.keySet();
for (Object key : keys) {
    hashMap.put(someObject, someValue); //it will throw the ConcurrentModificationException here
}
```

For HashTable enumeration:

```
 Enumeration keys = hashTable.keys();
 while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
          hashTable.put(someKey, someValue);  //this is ok
    }
```

Comment: The Hastable's iterators are fail-fast. Its enumerations are not.

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to probably look at the source for each class as implemented by the Open JDK implementation for each class; that way, you can get your answer straight from the horse's mouth, as it were :-)

That aside, essentially, "fail-fast" in this sense means that an Iterator over a HashMap will throw an exception if it detects that another thread has modified the targeted HashMap - if you look in the source for HashMap, you will see this is done by simply checking a counter for the number of expected modifications. If the modification count is different than the Iterator expected, that means that someone else has come in since the last check and messed around with the HashMap, and so the Iterator throws a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

A "non fail-fast" Iterator wouldn't bother to check, and happily go along it's business in the underlying data structure. Therefore, you gain some flexibility (probably dubious flexibility in this case) in exchange for possibly running into errors later; i.e. attempting to access a value that is no longer present.

As with all [fail-fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) strategies, the idea is that the earlier an error is detected, the easier it is to recover from or debug.

Comment: Not just another thread. If you modify the map while iterating over it, even in the same thread, a ConcurrentModification is thrown (except if you use the iterator itself to modify the map)

Comment: Very true! A sometimes confusing mistake I've done myself :-)

Answer (score 3):

When calling `iterator.next()`, if any modification has been made between the moment the iterator was created and the moment `next()` is called, a ConcurrentModificationException is immediately thrown. This is what fail-fast means.

The Enumerations returned by Hashtable don't have this behavior. They assume you know what you're doing, and their behavior, AFAIK, is undefined if you modify the map while iterating over it using one of its enumerations.