# fail fast behaviour of java HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrentmodification

I played around with `java.util.HashMap` to learn what the `fail-fast` behaviour is.

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put("jon", 10);
map.put("sean", 11);
map.put("jim", 12);
map.put("stark", 13);
map.put("vic", 14);
Set keys = map.keySet();
for(Object k:keys) {
    System.out.println(map.get(k));
}

for(Object k:keys) {
   String key =(String)k;
   if(key.equals("stark")) {
      map.remove(key);
    }
}

System.out.println("after modifn");
for(Object k:keys) {
    System.out.println(map.get(k));
}
```

I got the result

```
12
11
10
14
13
after modifn
12
11
10
14
```

I also tried using an iterator

```
Iterator<String> itr = keys.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    String key = itr.next();
    if(key.equals("stark")) {
        map.remove(key);
    }
}
```

I didn't get any `ConcurrentModificationException` in either case ..Is this because (from javadoc)

> the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is,
>   generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the
>   presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast
>   iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis

I checked another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751140/1291096) which says ,it WILL throw `ConcurrentModificationException`..what do you think?

Comment: Try calling `clear()` rather than `remove()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the output that you have shown:

```
12
11
10
14
13   // notice this?
after modifn
12
11
10
14
```

Since 13 is the last key-value pair, when you `Iterate` through your `HashMap` and then finally remove the key-value corresponding to `stark 13`, that stops the `Iteration` just after the `HashMap` has been modified, hence, it doesn't `iterate` anymore. So no `ConcurrentModificationException.`

Comment: thanks..I never noticed that..`if(key.equals("jon")) ` will throw the exception..